PhosphorIcon set background color on hover
I'm using PhosphorIcon in a react project, is there a way to set the bg color on hover instead of using two different instances and toggle(show/hide) via CSS?
  <a href='#' className='addTableButton'>
    <PlusSquare className='normal' size={32}  />
    <PlusSquare className='hover' size={32} color="#9f6786" weight="fill" />
  </a>

CSS
a.addTableButton {
  ...
  .hover {
    display: none;
  } 
}
a.addTableButton:hover {
  .hover {
    display: block;
  }
  .normal {
    display: none;
  }
}


Remove color prop:
<a href='#' className='addTableButton'>
    <PlusSquare className='hover' size={32} weight="fill" />
</a>

Use CSS to set its style like:
.addTableButton .hover { color: red }
.addTableButton:hover .hover { color: blue }

That should do the trick.

I understand that you are making a logical inference, but thats not how react-icons work, and I wanted to actually set the background, which the color attribute is applying in my example. And If i set the bg color using the css then that turns out into bg box with that color and not that icon accent turning to that color.

@MohdAbdulMujib I don't know what you're refering to as set the background. If you specify color property for your icons ( which I double checked with phosphor icons ) it will use that color as icon color itself and not its background. so I don't see why the solution is not working for you. don't you want to change the color of icon on hover?
